# ¿Como otorgar permisos en un fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estoy trabajando en una app que necesita realizar llamadas, mi problema es que no me realiza las llamada por que no tengo los permiso, ¿como otorgo los permisos dentro de un fragment?[image]

Comment: Nelson, recuerda que en el caso de código lo ideal es agregar una imagen, el problema es simplemente otorgar permisos, para dispositivos saludos.

Answer (score 1):

El permiso para realizar llamadas en dispositivos con OS 6.0+ se debe realizar manual, no es suficiente agregarlo en el AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

**al otorgar el permiso no es únicamente para un `Fragment` o una `Activity`, en realidad se otorga para toda la aplicación.**

Esta sería la forma de realizarlo:

```
//Defines una variable para el request code:
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS = 507;
```

Este `snippet` puede estar definido al iniciar tu aplicación, por ejemplo dentro de `onCreate()` de tu `Activity`, o de la `Activity` que contiene o realiza la transacción del `Fragmento`:

```
//Se realiza la petición de permisos para dispositivos con OS >= 6.0
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // Se tiene permiso
        Intent calIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        calIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:5553061234"));
        startActivity(calIntent);
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
        return;
    }
} else {
    // No se necesita requerir permiso, OS menor a 6.0.
}
```

en la misma `Activity` implementas el método :

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS:
            if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // El usuario acepto los permisos.
                Toast.makeText(this, "Gracias, aceptaste los permisos requeridos para el correcto funcionamiento de esta aplicación.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                // Permiso denegado.
                Toast.makeText(this, "No se aceptó permisos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

Esto será suficiente para posteriormente realizar sin problema la llamada telefónica:

```
Intent calIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
calIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:5553061234"));
startActivity(calIntent);
```

Comment: exelente rspuesta

Answer (score -2):

No tengo demasiada idea de Android, pero estuve haciendo varios cursos. Recuerdo que cuando no tienes permisos debes solicitarlos al método `requestPermissions()` para solicitar los permisos que te hagan falta. Es decir en el try puedes poner una llamada a lo que te hace falta para tu app, por ejemplo los contactos.

Aunque lo mejor es solicitar los permisos una vez que el usuario abre la app, es decir especificando lo que necesites en el `AndroidManifest.xml`, así no deberías luego especificar permisos en un fragment particular.

Algo asi:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Mas info: [Permissions in Android](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)